# Query Wins and Losses With Score

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table:

```
matches

id
team_one
team_two
one_score
two_score
```

How would I make a query giving me the following result:

```
Team A 

    Win: 2   Lose:  0  Score: 5


Team B

    Win: 2   Lose:  0  Score: 3


Team C

    Win:  1  Lose:  1  Score: 3


Team D

    Win:  0  Lose:  2  Score: 1
```

The Team who have won has the higher score in the table.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Shouldn't team B score be 5? B won twice same as A...

Comment: How are you counting ties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is that a given team may appear in one of two different columns. You can solve this with a UNION, where the second table for the union simply swaps the columns from the first table. After that it's just a simple GROUP BY:

```
SELECT team, SUM(Win) As Won, SUM(Loss) as Lost, SUM(score) as Score
FROM
( SELECT team_one as team, 
     CASE WHEN one_score > two_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Win, 
     CASE WHEN one_score < two_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Loss, one_score as score
  FROM matches
  UNION ALL
  SELECT team_two as team
     CASE WHEN two_score > one_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Win, 
     CASE WHEN two_score < one_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Loss, two_score as score
  FROM matches
) t
GROUP BY team
ORDER By Won, Lost DESC, Score
```

As an aside, I worked on a database system like this a long time ago, that had a table with paired records. This was not for competition results, but it was paired data. We found it a *lot* more performant to store two records for each "match". The two records for a match would share a common match_id, but reverse the order in which the "teams" were listed. Front end code and a backend maintenance task were used to guarantee the paired records were stored properly.

This made certain queries we needed to do much more efficient, as we could index the table once and select from the table for specific teams just by looking at its equivalent team_one column. Again, this wasn't sports data, so your results may vary, but we did find for our problem space it worked **much** better.

Part of what made this efficient in the old system was that, once entered, the paired data rarely changed. This seems like a good fit for what you're doing.